# python console app to return time from time.is

Tags: python, web-crawler

I'm trying to make a terminal app to crawl a website and return the time of the entered city name. this is my code so far:

```
import re
import urllib.request

city = input('Enter city name: ')
url = 'https://time.is/'
rawData = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
decodedData = rawData.decode('utf-8')
print(decodedData)
```

after the last line i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    rawData = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
  File "~/Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "~/Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 472, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "~/Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 582, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "~/Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 510, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "~/Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "~/Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

why do i get this error? what's wrong?

[EDIT]
the reason is time.is banns requests. Always remember to read terms and conditions when doing web scraping. free APIs can be found to do the same job too.

Comment: Seems like the website blocks requests from scripts?

Comment: oh thx, is there a way to realize if a website blocks the requests? except testing them one by one?

Comment: any particular reason for using time.is? theres a free api that would save you some time in parsing. https://timezonedb.com/api

Comment: @Nitwit Always read the Terms & Conditions or similar. time.is calls theirs [Terms of use](https://time.is/terms_of_use): "Time.is is made for humans. Automatic refresh and any usage from within scripts and apps is forbidden. If you need time synchronization for your app, please contact us about our API."

Comment: When you see that, they may be blocking scripts, or they may have a heuristic detector that figures out you're scripting them after a few requests and starts breaking them, or they may have a passive detector that just flags things and they have a human intentionally change the page to break a script that they've noticed. Or they may be doing none of these, but starting doing any of them tomorrow.

Comment: Also, this site in particular is all about AJAX requests that synchronize your local time (as your browser sees it) with their server, so even if you could download the main page, it would just be a mess of JavaScript that doesn't do you any good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this happens, I usually open the debugger and try to find out whats being called when I access the website. It seems like time.is doesn't like having scripts call their website.

A quick search yielded this:

```
1532027279136 0 161_(UTC,_UTC+00:00) 1532027279104
Time.is is for humans. To use from scripts and apps, please ask about our API. Thank you!
```

Here are some APIs you could use to build your project. https://www.programmableweb.com/category/time/api